# How can I change yank/delete to show relative line numbers during the yank/delete in evil?

Tags: evil, spacemacs, yank

I use `evil` via `spacemacs`.  When I use yank, it’s mostly whole line numbers – like `y20y`. To a lesser extent, this is often true of delete – `d10d`

Is there anything I can add to my Spacemacs config to toggle on the relative line numbers when I press the first `y` and to toggle it off if I complete or cancel the yank? And the same for delete? This would make it obvious how many lines I need to yank. It feels like something that should already exist because it is a quite common use case.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to install [relative-line-numbers](https://github.com/Fanael/relative-line-numbers) for this one

```
(require 'relative-line-numbers)

(defun yank-with-numbering ()
  (interactive)
  (relative-line-numbers-mode t)
  (call-interactively 'evil-yank)
  (relative-line-numbers-mode -1)
  )
(define-key
  evil-normal-state-local-map ;; or `evil-normal-local-map` if you want it globally
  (kbd "y")
  #'yank-with-numbering)
```

Maybe (I'm not sure) it's a good exercise that you try and code it yourself for deleting. You can find out the function name for `d` by doing `C-h k d` ("help on key 'd'").